# How to import photos+videos from iphone with IOS 7.0.4?

Tags: ios, macos, photos.app

Trying to import this with the Photos app on mac sierra v.10.12.1. When I go to the import option the iphone is not showing up? How can I import my photos & videos to my mac? What other way is there to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Photos app to import photos from your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to your Mac without using iCloud Photo Library. These steps also work for importing images from digital cameras and SD cards.

1. Make sure that you have the latest version of iTunes on your Mac. Importing photos to your Mac requires iTunes 12.5.1 or later.
2. Connect your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or digital camera to your Mac with a USB cable. If you're using an SD card, insert it into the SD slot on your Mac, or connect it using a card reader.
3. You might need to unlock your iOS device using your passcode. You might also see a prompt on the iOS device asking you to Trust This Computer. Tap Trust to continue.
4. On your Mac, the Photos app automatically opens. If it doesn't, open the Photos app.
5. The Photos app shows an Import screen with all the photos and videos that are on your connected device. If the Import screen doesn't automatically appear, click the Import tab at the top of the Photos app, or click the device's name in the Photos sidebar.
6. To import a selection of photos, click the ones you want, then click Import Selected. To import all new photos, click Import All New Photos.